# Web Components, Polymer and SystemJS

Tags: polymer, web-component, ecmascript-6, systemjs

Does Polymer and/or native Web Components use ES6's SystemJS modules technology?
https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

Or do they rely on their own asset management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existing Web Components don't really use SystemJS but it's now possible to use it with [systemjs-plugin-html](https://github.com/Hypercubed/systemjs-plugin-html/) to load HTML imports and circumvent the issues they have. SystemJS can redirect paths so that for example the same library expected in different locations can be redirected to the same file, and components can be more freely placed in different directories. Of course, this doesn't fix paths in the `<link rel="import">` tags of existing components but new components can be created without them, while still more flexibly re-using existing components.

I've written [an article](http://blog.charto.net/typescript/Taming-Polymer-with-SystemJS-and-TypeScript-part-1/) with [downloadable code](https://github.com/charto/Taming-Polymer-with-SystemJS-and-TypeScript-part-1) and a [working demo](http://blog.charto.net/demo/Taming-Polymer-with-SystemJS-and-TypeScript-part-1/) for how to use Polymer with SystemJS and TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

The Web Components specification is a set of four other specifications where one is about the HTML Imports technology. Web Components do not solve any module issues at a first glance. However, HTML Imports are the key to import components from anywhere into your app.

If you have componentA that imports a componentB and you import componentA into your web app, componentB is first imported and then componentA. So you kind of setup an implicit dependency tree that is resolved by HTML Imports automatically (which is why HTML Imports work asynchronously).

Comment: My main interest was whether or not there is a "convergence" where all the module/asset loaders can use the same Javascript window.System feature.  It would be really lovely to see the complexity of the JS environment decreasing rather than increasing!

Comment: (to be clear: by window.System I mean the object System in the global namespace.  It would be different for node) System is the implementation for module loading in es6.

Answer (score 1):

In short: **no**. They use [HTML Imports](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/) to manage components.

Comment: HTML Imports "hooks" are not specified in the spec as es6 Modules are via the System object. [Here](http://addyosmani.github.io/webcomponent-samples/polymer/modules/) is an example of Polymer using the es6 module Loader. If HTML Imports were based on the System object hooks, then all remote asset management would be done by the same core code in System. So if Polymer can do it, why not the native implementations?

Answer (score 0):

No. In fact SystemJS modules are not support in browser yet. Currently polymer and x-tag use HTML import to load web component, but Mozilla rollback the HTML import support in nightly build and want to seek for SystemJS instead. (Eventually HTML import might duplicate once SystemJS is supported in browser).

In Firefox OS they just import web component as normal js library and not use HTML import.

ex: gaia-switch element
https://github.com/gaia-components/gaia-switch